# Не срабатывает margin внутри вкладок

Tags: php, css, javascript

Собственно дело обстоит так: Есть вкладки(табы), внутри вкладки №1 есть блок authgame я ставлю на него margin: 10px 0 0 10px; и почему то не работает.
Вот код

HTML

```
    <div id="tab-outer">
<ul id="tab-wrapper">
<li><a href="#tab1">Вкладка 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-body">
<div id="tab1">
<div class="authgame">Слон</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Js

```
$(function(){
$('#tab-wrapper li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tab-body > div').hide();
$('#tab-body > div:first').show();
$('#tab-wrapper a').click(function() {
    $('#tab-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tab-body > div:visible').hide();
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
});
});
```

CSS

```
#tab-outer {
 font:normal 12px Arial,Sans-Serif;    
}
#tab-outer * {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;    
}
#tab-wrapper {
  list-style:none;
  height:30px;
}
#tab-wrapper li {
  float:left;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#tab-wrapper li a {
 display:block;
  padding:0px 20px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
background: rgb(230,230,230);
}
#tab-wrapper li.active a {
background: rgb(200,200,200);
color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
#tab-body > div {
background: rgb(190,190,190);
color: rgb(0,0,0);
height:300px; 
}
#tab1 table{
width: 100%;
}
.authgame{
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В следующий раз выкладывайте код на

http://jsfiddle.net/

http://codepen.io/

не работает, так как выше в приоритете стоит:

```
#tab-outer * {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gWWuK/

Убираем и все работает, http://jsfiddle.net/gWWuK/1/

**UPD**

Для отладки используй **google developer tools** (F12)

[image]

**UPD2**

на class
http://jsfiddle.net/gWWuK/2/

Comment: Спасибо. На следующий раз учту.

Comment: @NetSperes, не используй id, используй class

Comment: Но вкладка улетает тогда.

Comment: @NetSperes, обновил